# Upgrade agent missing from Capabilities in Sonatype Nexus OSS 2.14.15

Tags: upgrade, nexus

I am trying to upgrade from Sonatype Nexus OSS 2.14.15 to Nexus 3.20.    According to the instructions at [upgrade from 2 to 3](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/upgrading/upgrade-procedures#UpgradeProcedures-EnablingtheUpgradeCapabilityinVersion2.x) there should be an 'Upgrade:Agent' capability in version 2 that I can enable and get a token for version 3.    However, there is no such capability to add. There are just ~10  capabilities in the 'Create new capability' list'

I'm not finding any clues as to how to install or enable the upgrade capability.  Any tips appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are you logged in as the admin user?  My instance has at least twice that number, so suspect your permissions are restricted somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upgrade agent code only ships in the jetty bundled binaries, the war version of Nexus Repo doesn't have it.